# loading .csv file with multiple commas in the field using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have a table named 'table1' with the columns:

CSMembers,BCID,Total,Email.

The excel sheet contains the data for this table in this format:

```
     CSMembers       BCID                 Total           Email
        abc    2,5,7,9,12,17,22,32       10,000      abc@gmail.com
        xyz    1,3,5,7,9,12,17,20,22,33  12,500      xyz@gmail.com
        pqr    2,5,7,9,12,17,22,32       11,000      pqr@gmail.com
        ttt    2,5,7,9,12,17,22          9,800       ttt@gmail.com
```

the .csv file of this is :

```
CSMembers,BCID,Total,Email
abc,"2,5,7,9,12,17,22,32","10,000",abc@gmail.com
xyz,"1,3,5,7,9,12,17,20,22,33","12,500",xyz@gmail.com
pqr,"2,5,7,9,12,17,22,32","11,000",pqr@gmail.com
ttt,"2,5,7,9,12,17,22","9,800",ttt@gmail.com
```

I have used the following code:

```
 load data local infile 'H:/abc.csv' into table table1
 fields terminated by ',' 
 optionally enclosed by '"'
 lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 lines
 (CSMembers,BCID,Total,Email);
```

I am getting the following output:

```
CSMember    BCID    Total       Email
abc          2       10      abc@gmail.com

xyz          1       12      xyz@gmail.com

pqr          2       11      pqr@gmail.com

ttt          2       9       ttt@gmail.com
```

But i need this output:

```
CSMembers   BCID                    Total         Email
    abc  2,5,7,9,12,17,22,32       10,000      abc@gmail.com
    xyz  1,3,5,7,9,12,17,20,22,33  12,500      xyz@gmail.com
    pqr  2,5,7,9,12,17,22,32       11,000      pqr@gmail.com
    ttt  2,5,7,9,12,17,22          9,800       ttt@gmail.com
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong?
if I should change the code or the csv file content or both?
plese help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema for the table is possibly wrong **bcid** and **total** is probably defined as an int of some kind instead of a string. Numeric fields won't know whether a comma is a separator  to another field or simply dividing the number up so it is easily readable. Also input to numeric fields typically accepts the value up to the first non-numeric character i.e. the comma

Comment: For the total field, it should be possible to export a CSV file that does not put commas in numbers.

Comment: Another alternative for fixing `Total` column is to remove commas while loading data by using `SET` clause of `LOAD DATA INFILE`